# In quartz 2.2.1 there is any possibility to find a misfire jobs

Tags: misfire-instruction

How can i identify the misfire jobs in quartz.If there is any new feature added in quartz 2.2.1.I have to find Misfire jobs which are all scheduled  and i have to store the misfire jobs into RAMJobstore

Answer (score 0):

You can register a [TriggerListener](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/org/quartz/TriggerListener.html) that provides the triggerMisfired method that will be invoked whenever a trigger has been misfired. You can easily store the misfire information somewhere in your application and use it for whatever purposes you wish (e.g. to look up misfired jobs and reschedule them etc.).